# Many HTTP CONNECT request for not owned domains

Tags: apache-2.4, log-files, hacking

I had a cloud server with two ip, and each ip is configured respectively with `apache` and `wildfly` server. In each of them there are some domain/vhost setup in production.

Checking the apache access log (and also widlfy log on the same cloud) I see many HTTP CONNECT request like them:

```
192.99.xxx.xxx - - [21/Jun/2019:09:58:03 +0200] "CONNECT www.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"

118.24.xxx.xxx - - [21/Jun/2019:09:59:20 +0200] "CONNECT api.zxkjj.cn:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.4.4"
```

and so on..

Are some try to hack my server? Why I received them? And.. How to block it without write `iptables` rules for each domain or ip?

---

Additional Info:
I wish to block the unwanted request directly from apache configuration.
Dropping request with mod_security will be the best instead of http 403.

My httpd.conf is very simple:

A default virtual host with following setup:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    ServerName catchall
<Location />
Deny from all
  Options None
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

and a second virtualhost with following setup:

```
<VirtualHost myserverip:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydir"
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests Off
    <Directory "/var/www/mydir">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>

<Proxy *>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from www.mydomain.com
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

but I continue to get request in the second virtual host as explained in my first question.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It may well be that this server was put on a proxy list, because someone actually detected an open proxy on it.

The fact that CONNECT returns status 200 instead of status 405 is a good/bad indicator of this. If this server is not intended to proxy http requests then DISABLE the mod_proxy module in Apache.

If Apache works as a reverse proxy for Wildfly then at least disable mod_proxy_connect. If RewriteRule [P] is used for reverse proxying then check that it can only proxy to the Wildfly instance and not to random domain, for example by catching the HTTP_HOST variable and putting it in the RewriteRule like RewriteRule /wildfly https://%1/ [P] or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not attempt to hack your server. This is attempt to use your `apache` server as proxy. What you can do is to disable in `apache` config the CONNECT method:

With rewrite engine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(OPTIONS)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Via Allow/Deny (using [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/551046/293588)):

```
<Proxy *>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from yournetwork.example.com
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses

I'm not using apache as proxy for wildfly.
Simply apache works for php project and wildfly for java ones.

I try to off the mod_proxy in the apache but it can't work.
the CONNECT request in the access log go on..

Comment: @Giuseppe, try with rewrite rule

Comment: I wish to block the unwanted request directly from apache configuration.
Dropping request with mod_security will be the best instead of http 403.

My httpd.conf is very simple:

A default virtual host with following setup:

<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    ServerName catchall
<Location />
Deny from all
        Options None
</Location>
</VirtualHost>